# Testing a Redux action that dispatches 2 other functions with Jest?

Tags: redux, jestjs

I have a function (a Redux action) which calls 2 functions. I can't figure how how to test this with Jest:

This is my function:

```
import doSomething from 'redux/do-something';
import doSomethingElse from 'redux/do-something-else';

export default () => async dispatch => {
  await dispatch(doSomething());
  dispatch(doSomethingElse());
};
```

This is my test:

```
import doSomething from 'redux/do-something';
import doSomethingElse from 'redux/do-something-else';

import functionToTest from 'redux/function-to-test'

describe("functionToTest", ()=>{
    jest.mock('redux/do-something');
    jest.mock('redux/do-something-else');
    const dispatch = jest.fn();

    test('my test', ()=>{
        functionToTest()(dispatch);
        console.log(dispatch.mock.calls); // This returns an anonymous function
        console.log(doSomething) // This returns undefined 
    })

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to mock the default export for `do-something` and `do-something-else` and test that they get dispatched by the code under test.

If that is the case then you can do it like this:

```js
import functionToTest from 'redux/function-to-test'

jest.mock('redux/do-something', () =>
  () => 'do something mock'
);
jest.mock('redux/do-something-else', () =>
  () => 'do something else mock'
);

describe("functionToTest", () => {
  test('my test', async () => {  // <= async test function
    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    await functionToTest()(dispatch);  // <= await the Promise
    expect(dispatch.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('do something mock');  // Success!
    expect(dispatch.mock.calls[1][0]).toBe('do something else mock');  // Success!
  });
});
```

**Details**

You can pass a module factory function as the second paramter to `jest.mock` and `Jest` will use the result of calling the function as what it gives back when the module is imported during the test.

`jest.mock` calls get hoisted by `babel-jest` and run before everything else in the code file.  The hoisting [doesn't work right when `jest.mock` is defined in a test function](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582) so the `jest.mock` calls should be moved to the top level scope of the test file.

The function under test is `async` so use an `async` test function and `await` the `Promise` to make sure it has completed before asserting.

Comment: This works! At the risk of going off topic, does this look like an appropriate testing strategy for this type of function? For instance I don't think it would test the order in which doSomething() and doSomethingElse() were called.

Comment: Yep, this approach works fine!  (note that it's testing the order of `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` since the `dispatch` mock records the arguments it was called with in the order they were called in: `...mock.calls[0]...` and then `...mock.calls[1]...`)