# How to jest-test a redux-thunk action with two dispatches inside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs

I'm using react and redux-thunk.

I have this action here, to fetch documents from API (I need the dispatch to call it so I wouldn't like to remove it) and then save the docs on my store with a second dispatch:

```js
export function searchDocuments(search) {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const { loggedUser } = getState().userReducer;

        let documents = [];

        if (search.length > 1) {
            documents = await dispatch(apiSearchFiles(search, loggedUser));
        }

        return dispatch({
            type: UPDATE_SEARCH_DOCUMENTS,
            payload: documents,
        });
    };
}
```

And I'm trying test it with:

```js
describe('Call searchDocuments correctly', () => {
    it('should call the correct type on searchDocuments dispatch', async () => {
        const store = mockStore({
            userReducer: { loggedUser: { name: 'user1' } },
            documentsResults: [],
        });
        const payload = [{ name: 'doc1' }];
        const expectedActions = [{ type: UPDATE_SEARCH_DOCUMENTS, payload }];

        return store.dispatch(searchDocuments('searchTerm')).then(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
        });
    });
});
```

But I always got this error, pointing to this line:
Error:

`Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions`

Line:

`documents = await dispatch(gDriveSearchFiles(search, loggedUser));`

I tried to follow the approach from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056408/testing-a-redux-action-that-dispatches-2-other-functions-with-jest) but it didn't work for me, his action is a little different.

So I would like to know if there is any way to handle that first dispatch inside of my action.

Comment: Looks like you're not setting up your mock store with the redux thunk middleware

Comment: Yes I am, this is setup in another file. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: I guess the question is answered? If not, what other errors are you getting after setting up mock store with redux-thunk?

Comment: @Tunmee Sorry, in my last comment I meant that mock was already setup in another file.
But I found a solution for this question, I'll post here latter.